# Castle ActiveRecord - Issue With Setter

Tags: c#, castle-activerecord

Ok, so im starting a new project and decided to use a ORM tool (as im so bored with writing it manually)
So im starting new with Castle AR,

So in my domain object ive the following

```
[ActiveRecord]
    public class Account : ActiveRecordBase<Account>
    {
        private string companyName;
        private Guid accountId;

        [PrimaryKey(Access = PropertyAccess.FieldCamelcase)]
        public Guid AccountId
        {

            get { return accountId; }

        }

        [Property(Access = PropertyAccess.FieldCamelcase)]
        public string  CompanyName
        {
            get { return companyName; }
          //   set { companyName= value; }
        }
    }
```

And this works and pulls out my records.
But if I uncomment the set I get the following
[image]

Obviosuly im going to need the set soon
(normally I would also remove this on `CompanyName "Access=PropertyAccess.FieldCamelCase")`

Any ideas what im doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting `AccountId` in place of `accountId` which creates an infinite loop. Use the fix below:

```
set { accountId = value; }
```

You're also doing the same mistake with `CompanyName` also so fix that too.